# Extract words the include numbers in R

Tags: r, regex

I have words that include numbers within, or begin with or end with numbers. How do i extract those only.

```
s <- c("An ex4mple". "anothe 3xample" "A thir7", "And sentences w1th w0rds as w3ll")

Expected output:
c("ex4mple", "3xample", "thir7", "w1th w0rds w3ll")
```

Words could include more than one number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the strings by space into a `list`, loop through the elements with `sapply`, then match all words that have only letters from start (`^`) to end (`$`), specify `invert=TRUE` with `value=TRUE` to get those elements that don't fit the criteria, `paste` them together

```
sapply(strsplit(s, "\\s+"), function(x) 
  paste(grep("^[A-Za-z]+$", x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE), collapse=' '))
#[1] "ex4mple"         "3xample"         "thir7"           "w1th w0rds w3ll"
```

---

Or we can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(s, '[A-Za-z]*[0-9]+[A-Za-z]*'), paste, collapse=' ')
#[1] "ex4mple"         "3xample"         "thir7"           "w1th w0rds w3ll"
```

#### data

```
s <- c("An ex4mple", "anothe 3xample", "A thir7", "And sentences w1th w0rds as w3ll")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  @akrun